# How to create a multi dimensional array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a jQuery below format with help of using two each statements.

```
arrar [
  'aaa'=>'ccsdfccc',
  'bb'=>'aaddsaaaa',
  '1'=>[
      'three'=>'sdsds'
      'four'=>'eesdsee'
       ] 
  '2'=>[
      'one'=>'dcvcdd'
      'two'=>'eeee'
       ] 
    ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: here given for example format, not dublicate array

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In javascript there are 2 type of arrays: standard arrays and
>   associative arrays
>
> - `[ ]` - standard array - 0 based integer indexes only
> - `{ }` - associative array - javascript objects where keys can be any strings
>
> So when you define:
>
> ```
> var arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ];
> ```
>
> you are defining a standard array where indexes can only be integers.

So you can write this object

```
var obj = {
    'aaa': 'ccsdfccc',
    'bb': 'aaddsaaaa',
    '1': {
        'three': 'sdsds',
        'four': 'eesdsee'
    },
    '2': {
        'one': 'dcvcdd',
        'two': 'eeee'
    }
}
```

and then use it like `obj['1'].three`

Comment: simple arrays can have (custom) properties, because arrays are special objects.